# Query missing result If I use Php but is complete if I run in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query to get users and attendance of users on a span of date as shown below

```
select 
   u.user_id,
   u.username,
   min(case when a.action = 'IN' then date(a.server_time) end) `Date`,
   min(case when a.action = 'IN' then time(a.server_time) end) `IN`,
   max(case when a.action = 'OUT' then time(a.server_time) end) `OUT`
from 
   users u
   inner join user_attendance a on u.user_id = a.user_id AND  (a.server_time BETWEEN '2019-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-10-15 23:59:59')
group by
   u.user_id,
   u.username,
   date(a.server_time)
order by
   u.user_id,
   date(a.server_time)
```

If I run the query above in Mysql it will return a correct data as show below

[image]

But when I Run it with Php using the code below

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "lumenapi";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $dailyDate = date("Y-m-d");

    $sql = "select 
                u.user_id,
                u.username,
                min(case when a.action = 'IN' then date(a.server_time) end) `Date`,
                min(case when a.action = 'IN' then time(a.server_time) end) `IN`,
                max(case when a.action = 'OUT' then time(a.server_time) end) `OUT`
            from 
                users u
                inner join user_attendance a on u.user_id = a.user_id AND  (a.server_time BETWEEN '2019-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-10-15 23:59:59')
            group by
                u.user_id,
                u.username,
                date(a.server_time)
            order by
                u.user_id,
                date(a.server_time)";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "id: " . $row["user_id"]. " - Name: " . $row["username"]. " -Date: " .$row["Date"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

it will return to me the result below and as you can see, the result is different from the one I run in Mysql directly

[image]

disregard the columns just focus on the number of results and the date, mysql returns 2,7,9,10,15 for October but returns NULL, 10 and 15 only if I use the Php code.

Please help, I'm stuck here.

Comment: Something strange with your php printing. Based on your code I'd say it should not be dot/full stop before '-Date' in output. Can you try to dump it "as is" first?

Comment: the . is nothing to worry about. It was just an edited photo. Sorry.

Comment: I dumped the $row, still missing some items.

Comment: You sure that your direct connection and connection from php are to the same server/db? You can try to issue simple queries like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_attendance`

Comment: @fifonik, this one won't lead to empty dates because OP is using inner join.

Comment: I suggested that just to check if numbers are the same. If not -- I'd say it is definitely different databases.

Comment: @fifonik, yes, got what you mean. but min(date) even there's null values, it will still give the min date

Comment: Nope. If there is record with a.server_time = 2019-10-02 (the date is withing join ON dates range), BUT a.action for the row != 'IN', then the row will be in result set, but MIN value will be null so the blank in php output.

Comment: Solved.I have one query which is running (a little similar query than what I stated in my original post.) that is being called and the connection of the query is on another server. Anyways between your discussion I managed to check how to have those dates not null when displaying.
I placed this one on the query and display respectively

min(case when a.action = 'IN' then date(a.server_time) end) `DateIn`,
                    min(case when a.action = 'OUT' then date(a.server_time) end) `DateOut`,
<td>".($row['DateIn'] == '' ? $row['DateOut'] : $row['DateIn'])."</td>